# Unity։ Ошибка при создании apk

Tags: android, unity3d, build

У меня во время билда во всех проектах Unity даёт вот эту ошибку.

[image]

Потом когда нажимаю Ok получаю 3 ошибки -

1.

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar"
>   org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m"
>   "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':lintVitalRelease'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lintClassPath'.
>   >     Could not download trove4j.jar (org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824)
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar'.
>   >     Connection reset
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 6m 27s ] stdout[ :checkReleaseClasspath :preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :preReleaseBuild :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   :compileReleaseRenderscript :checkReleaseManifest
>   :generateReleaseBuildConfig :prepareLintJar
>   :mainApkListPersistenceRelease :generateReleaseResValues
>   :generateReleaseResources :mergeReleaseResources
>   :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests :processReleaseManifest
>   :splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease :processReleaseResources
>   :generateReleaseSources :javaPreCompileRelease
>   :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac :compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
>   :compileReleaseSources :lintVitalRelease Download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.2.0/intellij-core-26.2.0.jar
>   Download
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar
>   Download
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
>   :lintVitalRelease FAILED 16 actionable tasks: 16 executed ] exit code:
>   1 UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
>   (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
>   <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
>   <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
>   <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args,
>   System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String
>   error) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
>   (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String
>   workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at
>   <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0) Rethrow as
>   GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
>   (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String
>   workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at
>   <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
>   <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
>   <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

2.

> Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

3.

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors   at
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190
>   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Попробовал переустановить unity, создать новый проект, sdk обновить. Не помогло.

**Как решить эту проблему?**

Comment: Покажите полные логи. Если в юнити их нет, то из лог файл.

Comment: @Suvitruf пришлось только первую изменить. Остальные в Unity такие как я писал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я даже не знаю как объяснить решение. Так что я просто опишу то что сделал.
1. Я скачал все файлы из ссылок в первом логе. Там 3 разных JAR файла.
2. Потом я пытался их запускать, они не запустились.
3. Тогда я зашёл в Unity, сменил платформу на Windows и забилдил. К моему удивлению это прекрасно сработал.
4. Потом я сменил платформу на андроид и опять забилдил. Этот тоже сработал прекрасно.
**Всё, счастливый конец.**

Answer (score 1):

Я решил эту проблему следующим образом, шагаем в папку `Assets>Plugins>Android`
Там открываем MainTemplate.gradle и там добавляем этот код

```
android {
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
```

Может кому-то будет полезным